# IF formula for diesel prices

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is the chart I am needing a formula for. 
First column is low end, middle column is high end, and last column is the cents per mile for anything between those 2 columns.

Example data:

```
1.351   1.400   0.05
1.401   1.450   0.06
1.451   1.500   0.07
1.501   1.550   0.08
1.551   1.600   0.09
1.601   1.650   0.10
1.651   1.700   0.11
1.701   1.750   0.12
1.751   1.800   0.13
1.801   1.850   0.14
1.851   1.900   0.15
1.901   1.950   0.16
1.951   2.000   0.17
2.001   2.050   0.18
2.051   2.100   0.19
2.101   2.150   0.20
```

[image: pic of fuel chart]

J2 is where the weekly price of diesel will be listed. 
For example, this week, the average is 1.989. So fuel is 17 cents a mile for this particular chart.

This is the formula i figured out so far, but this is only for ONE line item. I can't figure out how to do more than one.

```
=IF(AND(J2>=1.951,J2<=2),0.17,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one simple `INDEX` and `MATCH` formula for this:

In one cell, enter the current price. I'm using `F12` for this example.

Then, use the formula:

```
=INDEX(L2:L17,MATCH(F12,J2:J17,1))
```

Where `L2:L17` are the units you want returned, `F12` is the current price, and `J2:J17` are the lower end prices.

[image]